# menu bar is overlapping with content

Tags: html, css

when ever i open my menu bar in mobile screen size it over laps with content but this only happens with the product page on the home page it doesn't overlaps with the content  there is not Z index on the product cards

[menu-bar overlapping img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfkPL.jpg)

here's the css of menu bar

css code

```
 @media (max-width: 768px) {
  #menu-bar {
    display: initial;
    z-index: 9999;
  }

#menu-bar {
  font-size: 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid var(--black);
  padding: 0.8rem 1.5rem;
  color: var(--black);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}
```

javascript code:

```
    let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-bar');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
let header = document.querySelector('.header-2');

menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('fa-times');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
});

window.onscroll = () => {
    menu.classList.remove('fa-times');
    navbar.classList.remove('active');

    if (window.scrollY > 150) {
        header.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        header.classList.remove('active');
    }

}
```

HTML code :

```
<div class="header-2">
        <div id="menu-bar" class="fas fa-bars"></div>

        <nav class="navbar">
          <a href="index.html">home</a>
          <a href="#product">products</a>
          <a href="#category">Category</a>
          <a href="about.html">about</a>
          <a href="#contact">contact</a>
        </nav>

        <div class="icons">
          <a href="login.html">Login</a>
          <a href="#" class="fas fa-user-circle"></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough code, so I can just guess.
This is definitely a z-index problem and possible reasons are:

1. Your product cards (their children) have a z-index >=9999, which means it's just bigger than the menu z-index.
2. Your menu is located in parent with a smaller z-index than the menu on its own. In that case, you have a [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) issue, so your menu z-index is actually not 9999 (so it's smaller than cards z-index)

Comment: let menu = document.querySelector('#menu-bar');
let navbar = document.querySelector('.navbar');
let header = document.querySelector('.header-2');

menu.addEventListener('click', () => {
    menu.classList.toggle('fa-times');
    navbar.classList.toggle('active');
});

window.onscroll = () => {
    menu.classList.remove('fa-times');
    navbar.classList.remove('active');

    if (window.scrollY > 150) {
        header.classList.add('active');
    } else {
        header.classList.remove('active');
    }

}/// this is the javascript code

Comment: @Ibadhussain add HTML and CSS, there is no need to add Javascript, your problem is not related to javascript

Comment: i have edited the question can you please check it

Comment: @Ibadhussain you should create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Now your problem can not be reproduced. I have already gave you good starting point - you need to check your z-indexes